# overrideParameters is complaining for ArmDeployment in AzurePipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

with that I have run my arm template

```
parameters:
  - name: StartDate
    displayName: StartDate
    type: string
  - name: EndDate
    displayName: EndDate
    type: string
```

...

...

```
      - task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@3
        inputs:
          ConnectedServiceName: "${{ parameters.ServiceConnection }}"
          resourceGroupName: "${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}"
          action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
          templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
          csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/mytemplate.json'
          deploymentName: "${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}-deploy"
          deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
          deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
          overrideParameters: -EndDate "${{ parameters.EndDate }}" -StartDate "${{ parameters.StartDate }}"
```

and it worked properly. However AzurePipeline complains

```
There was an error while overriding 'EndDate' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
There was an error while overriding 'StartDate' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
```

the parameters have been used like that in an earlier stage and also worked there with that  syntax. According to the documentation the syntax overrideParameters should be

```
-EndDate $(parameters.EndDate)
```

which didn't work at all for me. Can someone explain what is the propper way and why it works and complains at the moment ?

Comment: can you show the parameters defintions.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger edited for that. again the parameters work in other tasks as shown

Comment: Try adding quotes to your value ```-EndDate "Value"```.  As the error says, it is not in JSON format. To diagnose your problem, first pass your value as hard coded. Once you fix the format then you can pass it accordingly.

Comment: @DillyB the value has been accepted through input and worked already in the other tasks and was set correctly for the arm template. The strange thing is why does it complan than and what could be done to have no complains ?